# Python code works in 2.7 but not in 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe, python-3.5

My coursework is to create Tic Tac Toe in Python, my tutor helped me get it working in 2.7 however It needs to be in 3.5.

Firstly in 2.7 the code below prints a 3x3 list, however in 3.5 it just prints the list downwards not 3x3. my tutor said maybe put `end = ' '` at the end but that also doesn't work.

```
def printBoard( board ):
    counter = 0   
    for y in range(3):    
        for x in range(3):    
            print (board[counter]),    
            counter += 1    
        print    
    print
```

second problem is on 2.7 it allows me to continue to input numbers till the board is filled with X or O, on 3.5 it only allows to input once and then the program ends?

```
value = input("input number between 1 and 9")    
value = int(value)        
if value == 1:    
    alist[0] = player1    
    printBoard( alist )    
    value = input("input number between 1 and 9")    
if value == 2:    
    alist[1] = player1    
    printBoard( alist )    
    value = input("input number between 1 and 9")
```

etc.

Comment: You have used `value = int(value)` only once, you should use it everytime when you want to take input as `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `print` changed from [statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) to [a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) in Python 3.x. To print a statement without newline, you need to pass `end=' '` parameter (You can use the `print` as a function in Python 2.7 if you put `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning of the code):

   ```
   print(board[counter], end=' ')
   ```
2. `input` returns a string in Python 3.x. (does not evaluate the input string). You need to convert the value into `int` every where you used `input`:

   ```
   value = input("input number between 1 and 9")
   value = int(value)
   ```

   Alternatively, instead of comparing the input with integer literal `1` or `2`, compare the input string with strings: `'1'`, `'2'` without converting the string into integer. (But this requires you to use `raw_input` in Python 2.7 instead of `input`)
3. `print` should be called: `print()`. Otherwise, nothing is printed.

Comment: changing 1 to '1' worked thanks a lot man, however the print(board[counter], end = '') only prints the list across rather then downwards now.

Comment: def printBoard( board ):
    counter = 0
    for y in range(3):
        for x in range(3):
            print( board[counter], end='')
            counter += 1
        print

    this is how the list printed, im working in 3.5,                                         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 input number between 1 and 9

Comment: use `print()` in place of `print` to move text to new line.

Comment: "thanks for your answer, but it's still not producing the right result" - "you should accept this answer." Uh...

Answer (score 0):

I assume `board` is something like `[['*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*']]`. That means you have an easy way of printing this with a single `print()` call.

```
print(*(''.join(row) for row in board), sep='\n')
```

This joins each row into a new string, producing each row as part of a generator. This generator is unpacked with `*` and sent to `print()`, where each row is separated by a newline.

For your second issue, the problem is simple: you cast `int()` for the first `value`, but not for the subsequent ones. However, this is the sort of thing you should be doing with a loop. It'll prevent exactly this kind of bug. If you find yourself writing lots of code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, you're doing something wrong. If each block is slightly different, with an incremented number, you would do that with something like `for i in range(n):`, which allows you to execute the same code with an incremented number on each iteration.

However, I'd recommend a simple `while` loop that checks if the game is complete:

```
while True:
    move = request_move()
    do_move('X', move)
    if game_complete():
        break
    request_move()
    do_move('O', move)
    if game_complete():
        break
```

You would then write appropriate functions to request move coordinates, input moves into the board, and check if the game is complete yet.

Comment: I also recently posted [my own implementation of TTT](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111386/text-based-tic-tac-toe-with-dry-and-pep-8) on CR if you want to take a look.